# Changing Size from small to big in array or duplication

Tags: bezier-curves, modifiers

i want to have a couple of spheres from small to big along a curve/spline. Is there an easy way with modifiers etc. to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can do this using modifiers. You need an array and curve modifier.

[image]

1. Create a curve
2. Add a sphere
3. Add an empty (plain axis)
4. Select Sphere and add an array modifier

   - turn off Relative Offset
   - enable Object Offset and chose the empty
5. move the empty along a axis (possibly the positive x-axis)
6. scale the empty down a bit, you should see the spheres get smaller towards the end

   [image]
7. Select the sphere and add a curve modifier to it. Choose your curve
8. Depending on the orientation of the curve and the translation of the empty the array may look wrong. In this case move the empty along the other axis. You can also apply the transforms of the sphere and the curve using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Vader! Never thought about a particle system...

Comment: Thats a smart solution and it works fine, but it is really hard to control the deformation, caused by the curve modifier. But i can handle that. Thanks again!