# Using array modifier to array an object between 2 curves

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

I want to array the object I outlined with yellow between 2 red lines I've drawn here. I tried some of the array options to no avail. How can I do that?
It would be great even if you could just forward me to previous solutions for this one. I'm trying to make stadiums for FIFA and these objects are crowd meshes. Creating crowd meshes one-by-one is wasting a lot of time.

Thanks in advance, stay safe.

[image: here it is]

Edit: Actually this is what I want to do; [Change scale of objects in array without affecting distance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40807/change-scale-of-objects-in-array-without-affecting-distance)
but dupliframes are not included with latest Blender version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array Modifier's *Fit Length* or *Fit Curve* options

- Fit Length - specify a maximum length of arrayed objects (use the length slider)
- Fit Curve - use a curve to determine the length (adjust the curve to control length)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help, using fit length worked for arraying, but I also want them to be scaled around the red lines. How can I do that?

Comment: Actually this is what I want to do; https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40807/change-scale-of-objects-in-array-without-affecting-distance but dupliframes are not included with latest Blender version

Comment: Add en empty at the same position as your arrayed object, set the empty as the object offset in the array modifier, and scale the empty. Every iteration will be scaled by the same amount. You can scale either on x, y, or z, or any combination of axes

Comment: It seems like I have to research on adding empties. Are there any videos for that?