# Trying to use array with mesh going from big to small. Meshes are alternately flipping

Tags: modifiers

I've been following the instructions here: [Changing Size from small to big in array or duplication](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7375/changing-size-from-small-to-big-in-array-or-duplication)

It's not going well, however, and being new to this method, I cannot understand what the issue is. Any help would be immensely appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 2):

In an Object-Offset array, whatever transform would take the original array element to the Object will be repeated for each subsequent element.

[image]

So if (top row) the controlling Empty is offset in Y, and scaled by -1, then subsequent elements will have the offset from the previous element scaled by 1, -1, 1, .... . The scale multiplies.

To get shrinking elements, scale the Empty to a positive fraction of 1. (0.8 in the bottom row, with no Y offset, giving 0.8, 0.64, 0.512....)