# How to create a curved strip texture that goes along mesh?

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, sculpting, texture-baking

I am attempting to model/sculpt a snail and I was wondering how I would go about giving the shell some lines that bump up and down so I could bake the texture to a lower poly model.

Something like this: [image]

I'd just like some help with adding those line textures, but actually on the model not a material. They simultaneously move up the model and curve around the shell. The only way I could think to do it would manually be with a sculpt or doing some fancy vertices transforms.

Both of which, would take 5 ever.

Any help or tips appreciated, thanc.

Here's a high quality pic I found that shows what I'm trying to go for really well.

[image]

Comment: you could mark seam, unwrap, then use an addon like UV Squares to make the UV orthogonal, and you'll be able to have a texture that will follow the spiral, but maybe share your file so that we can give a try? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Can we see the topology of your model?

Comment: Here's a link to the file, too big for share sites. The topology is atrocious right now, I haven't done the retopology because I want the shells curved lines to be part of the texture on the bake. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FGKgHOMuzNSBJ0Ulwt7xoXRg_tQyTPyK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Don't edit my post if you aren't gonna contribute dude

Comment: No offensive but if you don't want people to edit your post then add the required info to your question (topology, a note that it's a sculpt and meaningful title). Else this question can't be found by people that have a similar problem and it's not very helpful to others. Please keep in mind this is a Q&A site and the questions & answers should not only help you but also others. Cheers.

Comment: I understand that completely but if it is tagged as sculpting... Then it will be found with a relevant search, adding specifically snail shell makes the question to specific, instead adding contoured lines is general enough to have several use cases(cans, planes, springs, etc, etc). 

And you editing grammar is fine but taking away my thanc, and 5 ever seems a little odd, it doesn't hurt anyone and a small amount of comedy won't ruin the site.

Comment: Yes, using tags is a good practice. But it doesn't hurt to mention that it's a sculpt in the title & in the text. I've overlooked the tag. And I was not the only one. Have a look at moonboot's and Robin Bett's comments. It was not clear that your model is a high-poly sculpt. Furthermore, on the mobile version of BSE you only see the title & no additional text. So having a descriptive title saves readers time & clicks. Last but not least, keep in mind that someone who wants to model a snail will ask google for "blender snail" and not "how to model this mesh" - a very popular title here  ;-)

Comment: @Blunder I did catch that it was a high-poly sculpt, however the misspellings for humor were a bad idea since stackexchange users that have misspelled typically have also been harder to help because it all came from a low effort budget: getting the spelling and punctuation right was just too expensive. Kind of like making an arithmetic “error” for humor on your business resume. You can make a joke, just make sure that in context it is CERTAIN to be taken for such.

Comment: I guess you need to retopologize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to generate a geometry like this is using arrays.
[image]

***Details for Blender 2.93.4***

1. Add a torus to a scene and edit it to have a lip like shown below.
   [image]
2. Add an empty.
3. Select the torus and add an array modifier.
   [image]
4. Modify the properties of the empty as shown below. This will cause the array to get smaller, rotate, and shift. For more details see [Changing Size from small to big in array or duplication](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7375/changing-size-from-small-to-big-in-array-or-duplication)
   [image]

An example in Blender 2.93.4 is available here - [image]

Comment: Hey thanks this is a really great example and I didn't even know about array until now. Thanks and solved!