# How to control the space between objects using Array modifier

Tags: modifiers

I'm following this tutorial here:[Changing Size from small to big in array or duplication](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7375/changing-size-from-small-to-big-in-array-or-duplication)

And is there a way to control the spacing between the objects, because along the path, the objects spacing is not symmetrical.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You use this setting: *Offset* in the Array modifier. Make sure your scale is applied, and you might have to fiddle with trying constant or relative offset to get the results you want.

Edit: Just noticed you're using object offset, this would make the spacing reliant on the distance between the offset empty object and the array object. If one of your models is 1.5 M from the empty and the other is 1 M then the array will reflect that in the gaps between each array instance.

Comment: Thanks for that, worked well.